# Can't find the Tails subkey!

Tags: tails, fingerprinting, private-key

I know I've seen it somewhere but now I can't find it. Why aren't the subkeys displayed on the same page as the primary key here???:

https://tails.boum.org/doc/get/trusting_tails_signing_key/index.en.html

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the subkey here:

https://tails.boum.org/download/index.en.html#verify